# Getting push alert on build completion

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2022

This is odd.  When a scheduled 2:30 AM build completes, Azure DevOps Server *fires a notification that someone pushed new changes* to the repo.  This is built with the classic azure pipelines engine.

The build is quite simple, there is no push or commit or anything in the build tasks.  The pipeline just generates a build number and compiles the application.  This build fires at 2:30 am.  Nobody is working at that time.  This is a build set to fire on a schedule only.

Has anyone else ran into this?

I may just have to remove the tasks one by one to identify which task is doing this... but then I would have no idea how to stop that.

Does a scheduled automated build normally fire a Push Notification maybe?  I have no idea why it would...

I have checked my notifications.  I DO have a rule setup to notify me when anyone pushes to the repo... That however shouldn't fire when a scheduled automated build competes.  A push is a push, a build is a build.

I have a separate build that triggers when a dev pushes to our repo.  I get that push notification and the build notification like I would expect.

The scheduled one is just strange... i have no idea what is going on...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  There is a checkbox in the pipeline that asks if you want to update your git repo with a badge for the build status.  That counts as a push to git, so that sends the notification.

There is no new commit, only a new badge generated... a bit misleading...

[image]

I realize it is a change to git, but.. the email doesn't mention this is just a badge.  The mail just says there's a new push.

Comment: Yes. This exactly is the option to add a label to the commit to show the status of the builds run for the commit. Also has similar feature available for release pipelines.

Comment: In addition, maybe you can accept yourself answer as a solution of this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions.